# Does the Team foundation server check in real time in server?

Tags: version-control, tfs

I am new to TFS and I have been using SVN before.

First question: In TFS once you modify and checkin your file, does the server gets the latest change automatically without checking out in the server part?

Second question: If not, where do the TFS save the file after I checkin from my local?

My purpose is, I want to bypass the checkout from the server, I want that whoever checkins will reflect on the server automatically.

Answer (score 0):

A check-in operation uploads your changes to the server immediately (just like SVN).